# How to resolve - "the expanded size of the tensor (1296) must match the existing size (512) at non-singleton dimension 1" this error?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, nlp, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model

I am trying to classify text with a Bangla data set by a transformer model. To do this, I am using the PyTorch framework to build the neural network model architecture. But I am facing an error with the model. Below I am attaching the code snippets for your better understanding:

> Tokenizing the text

```
stemmer = BanglaStemmer()
df["comment"] = df["comment"].apply(lambda x: " ".join([stemmer.stem(word) for word in word_tokenize(x)]))
```

> Splitting Dataset

```
train_text, val_text, train_labels, val_labels = train_test_split(df["comment"], df["threat_label"], test_size=0.3, random_state=42)
```

> Loading the pre-trained transformer model and tokenize the text using the
> tokenizer

```
model_class = ppb.BertModel
tokenizer_class = ppb.BertTokenizer
pretrained_weights = 'sagorsarker/bangla-bert-base'

tokenizer = tokenizer_class.from_pretrained(pretrained_weights)
model = model_class.from_pretrained(pretrained_weights)
```

> Convert the text into tokens, pad the sequences, and create attention
> masks
>
> **Train**

```
   # Tokenize the text
    tokenized_train_text = train_text.apply((lambda x: tokenizer.encode(x, add_special_tokens=True)))
    # print(tokenized_train_text)
    tokenized_val_text = val_text.apply((lambda x: tokenizer.encode(x, add_special_tokens=True)))
    # print(tokenized_val_text)
    
    # Pad the sequences
    max_len = max_length
    padded_train_text = np.array([i + [0]*(max_len-len(i)) for i in tokenized_train_text.values])
    # print(padded_train_text)
    padded_val_text = np.array([i + [0]*(max_len-len(i)) for i in tokenized_val_text.values])
    # print(padded_val_text)
    
    # Create attention masks
    attention_train_masks = np.where(padded_train_text != 0, 1, 0)
    # print(attention_train_masks)
    attention_val_masks = np.where(padded_val_text != 0, 1, 0)
    # print(attention_val_masks)
```

> Validation:
> This is as same as **Train**.

> Creating Tensors

```
# Convert the data into PyTorch tensors
train_text_tensor = torch.tensor(padded_train_text)
# print(train_text_tensor)

val_text_tensor = torch.tensor(padded_val_text)
# print(train_text_tensor)

train_labels_tensor = torch.tensor(padded_train_label)
val_labels_tensor = torch.tensor(padded_val_label)

train_masks_tensor = torch.tensor(attention_train_masks)
val_masks_tensor = torch.tensor(attention_val_masks)
```

> Creating a PyTorch DataLoader to feed the data into the model for
> training

```
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset, DataLoader, RandomSampler, SequentialSampler

batch_size = 32

# Create the DataLoader for training data
train_data = TensorDataset(train_text_tensor, train_masks_tensor, train_labels_tensor)
train_sampler = RandomSampler(train_data)
train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_data, sampler=train_sampler, batch_size=batch_size)
print(len(train_data[0][2]))

# Create the DataLoader for validation data
val_data = TensorDataset(val_text_tensor, val_masks_tensor, val_labels_tensor)
val_sampler = SequentialSampler(val_data)
val_dataloader = DataLoader(val_data, sampler=val_sampler, batch_size=batch_size)
```

> **The model where I am getting the error. The line is `outputs = model(batch_text, attention_mask=batch_masks)`**

```
# Define the hyperparameters
epochs = 4
lr = 2e-5

# Set the device to GPU if available, otherwise, CPU
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

# Freeze the pre-trained parameters
for param in model.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False

# Add a new classification layer
model.classifier = torch.nn.Sequential(torch.nn.Linear(768, 2), torch.nn.Softmax())

# Move the model to the device
model.to(device)

# Define the optimizer and loss function
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.classifier.parameters(), lr=lr)
loss_fn = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

# Train the model
for epoch in range(epochs):
    model.train()
    train_loss = 0
    train_accuracy = 0
    for step, batch in enumerate(train_dataloader):
        batch_text = batch[0].to(device)
        # print(batch_text.size())
        batch_masks = batch[1].to(device)
        batch_labels = batch[2].to(device)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = model(batch_text, attention_mask=batch_masks)
        loss = loss_fn(outputs[0], batch_labels)
        train_loss += loss.item()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        predictions = torch.argmax(outputs[0], dim=1)
        train_accuracy += accuracy_score(predictions.cpu().numpy(), batch_labels.cpu().numpy())
    train_loss /= len(train_dataloader)
    train_accuracy /= len(train_dataloader)
```

> Error message is

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/transformers/models/bert/modeling_bert.py in forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, token_type_ids, position_ids, head_mask, inputs_embeds, encoder_hidden_states, encoder_attention_mask, past_key_values, use_cache, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, return_dict)
    983             if hasattr(self.embeddings, "token_type_ids"):
    984                 buffered_token_type_ids = self.embeddings.token_type_ids[:, :seq_length]
--> 985                 buffered_token_type_ids_expanded = buffered_token_type_ids.expand(batch_size, seq_length)
    986                 token_type_ids = buffered_token_type_ids_expanded
    987             else:

RuntimeError: The expanded size of the tensor (1296) must match the existing size (512) at non-singleton dimension 1.  Target sizes: [32, 1296].  Tensor sizes: [1, 512]
```

**Note: This is my first time creating any Neural Network model with PyTorch. I am familiar with TensorFlow.**

Comment: The model you are using, only supports up to 512 tokens per sequence. Depending on your task, you either want to truncate your text or split it into several sequences.

Comment: @cronoik Yes. I pass truncate = True and worked but the code base was another. Thank you.